# How to create new Virtual Machine (VMWare) on OSX?

Tags: macos, vmware-player

Is there any **free** product that I can use to create new VMWare Windows virtual machine on OSX 10.6.2?

Is seems to me that there is no OSX version for VMWare Player.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any free version of VMware for OS X. You only get [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html), with a trial version though. This should give you time to set up the VM.

---

You can always open existing `vmdk` VMware disk images with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) though. You can also use VirtualBox to create a VM in the default `vdi` format, and then use the provided tools to convert it to a VMware-compatible `vmdk` file.

Use something similar to the following command [found in this tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-convert.html):

```
VBoxManage clonehd source.vdi target.vmdk --format VMDK
```

Note that you should probably uninstall any VirtualBox-specific guest tools before you boot it up in VMware.

Answer (score 0):

The only VMware product for OS X is [Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html), and that's commercial. It has a 30 day trial version though, so that might work if it's only about *creation* of the VM.